# Joining elements of a list if those elements are in between two whitespaces

Tags: python, list, join, slice, whitespace

I have an input like this:

```
['assembly', '', 'py', 'tho', 'n', '', 'ja', 'va', '', 'rub', 'y', '', 'java', 'script', '', 'c++']
```

I want to join elements between `''` to have an output like this:

```
['assembly', 'python', 'java', 'ruby', 'javascript', 'c++']
```

I tried using `join` and list slicing like this:

```
a=['assembly', '', 'py', 'tho', 'n', '', 'ja', 'va', '', 'rub', 'y', '', 'java', 'script', '', 'c++']
a[2:5] = [''.join(a[ 2: 5])]
a=['assembly', '', 'python', '', 'ja', 'va', '', 'rub', 'y', '', 'java', 'script', '', 'c++']
```

This works to some extent but I don't know how to iterate this instruction for the entire list.

Answer (score 28):

Using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

l = ['assembly', '', 'py', 'tho', 'n', '', 'ja', 'va', '', 'rub', 'y', '', 'java', 'script', '', 'c++']
new_l = [''.join(g) for k, g in groupby(l, key = bool) if k]
```

Output:

```
['assembly', 'python', 'java', 'ruby', 'javascript', 'c++']
```

Comment: Explanation: This uses "bool" to check for a "Falsey" value, like an empty string or None.

Answer (score 7):

This is awful and hacky, but

```
lambda b:lambda l:''.join(i or b for i in l).split(b)
```

can take any string you can guarantee is not contained in the concatenation of the list, and return a function doing what you want. Of course, you probably want to only use this once or twice for your specific situation, so, if you can guarantee that no element of the list contains a space, it might look more like:

```
a = ['assembly', '', 'py', 'tho', 'n', '', 'ja', 'va', '', 'rub', 'y', '', 'java', 'script', '', 'c++']
a = ''.join(i or ' ' for i in a).split(' ')
```

Answer (score 4):

If you can't or don't want to use itertools:

```
l = ['assembly', '', 'py', 'tho', 'n', '', 'ja', 'va', '', 'rub', 'y', '', 'java', 'script', '', 'c++']
l_new = []
combined = ""
for idx, s in enumerate(l):
    if s != "":
        combined += s
        if idx == len(l)-1:
            l_new.append(combined)

    else:
        l_new.append(combined)
        combined = ""
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
a = ['assembly', '', 'py', 'tho', 'n', '', 'ja', 'va', '', 'rub', 'y', '', 'java', 'script', '', 'c++']
indx = ['' == k for k in a]
indx = [i for i, x in enumerate(indx) if x] # get the indices.
a_merged = a[0:indx[0]] + [''.join(a[indx[i]:indx[i+1]]) for i in range(len(indx)) if i < len(indx)-1] + a[indx[-1]+1:] # merge the list
```

Output:

```
['assembly', 'python', 'java', 'ruby', 'javascript', 'c++']
```

Edit after comments:

```
a = ['assembly', '','',  'py', 'tho', 'n', '', 'ja', 'va', '', 'rub', 'y', '', 'java', 'script', '', 'c++']
indx = [i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x == ''] # get the indices where '' occurs in the original list. 
a_merged = a[0:indx[0]] + [''.join(a[indx[i]:indx[i+1]]) for i in range(len(indx)) if i < len(indx)-1 and indx[i+1] -indx[i] > 1] + a[indx[-1]+1:]
a_merged
```

Output:

```
['assembly', 'python', 'java', 'ruby', 'javascript', 'c++']
```

Comment: `# get the indices.` is not a very useful comment. I would suggest you either make it useful (e.g. `filter the indices to keep only those that correspond to whitespace`), or remove it entirely.

Comment: Also, couldn't that 2 step process  just be simplified to `indices = [i for s in a if s == '']`?

Comment: @Alexander I think your suggestion for line 2 would be a syntax error.  Line 2 can be removed if you simply add the "is equal to null string" check to line three like `indx = [i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x == '']`

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer does not account for the first or last element being something that should be joined. like `a = ['asse','mbly', '', 'py', 'tho', 'n', '', 'ja', 'va', '', 'rub', 'y', '', 'java', 'script', '', 'c+', '+']` but it looks like you could improve your line 3 by appending a list with a null string on the ends of a `enumerate([''] + a + [''])` then  removing the `a[0:indx[0]]` and `a[indx[-1]+1:]` on your line 4. This still doesn't account for if there are two null strings right next to eachother though

Comment: @KeiNagase Ah, yes, that's what I had in mind, tahnks for the fix

Answer (score 3):

If the input delimiters are actually empty strings, then you can do

```
strlist = [x or ' ' for x in a]
joined = ''.join(strlist).split()
joined
['assembly', 'python', 'java', 'ruby', 'javascript', 'c++']
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't see Unrelated String's answer. If you split() without a parameter, it will collapse all the whitespace, which is a bit more robust.

Answer (score 1):

run a loop over the list
inside the loop append the element to a temporary empty string and  check for the condition whether the element is an empty string or last element of the list, if true then append the temporary variable to output list and change the value of that variable to a empty string
**Code:**

```
x=['assembly', '', 'py', 'tho', 'n', '', 'ja', 'va', '', 'rub', 'y', '', 'java', 'script', '', 'c++']
temp=''
output=[]
for y in x:
    temp=temp+y
    if y=='' or y==x[-1]:
        output.append(temp)
        temp=''

print(output)
```

**Output:**
`['assembly', 'python', 'java', 'ruby', 'javascript', 'c++']`

Answer (score 1):

Pretty old but still useful:

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = ['assembly', '', 'py', 'tho', 'n', '', 'ja', 'va', '', 'rub', 'y', '', 'java', 'script', '', 'c++']

new_lst = [''.join(values)
           for key, values in groupby(lst, key = lambda x: x == '')
           if not key]
print(new_lst)
```

This yields

```
['assembly', 'python', 'java', 'ruby', 'javascript', 'c++']
```

Answer (score 1):

I would agree that **[Cris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58800462/7221283)** answer **use most python approach**, but it will be good to adapt the **[Cris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58800462/7221283)** answer a bit. 
Instead of using `groupby(l,key = bool)` to use `groupby(l, key = lambda x: x !='')` and get rid of **unnecessary ambiguity**

```
from itertools import groupby

separator = ''
l = ['assembly', '', 'py', 'tho', 'n', '', 'ja', 'va', '', 'rub', 'y', '', 'java', 'script', '', 'c++']
new_l = [''.join(g) for k, g in groupby(l, key = lambda x: x !=separator) if k]
```

> As it is stated in [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): **Explicit is better than
>   implicit**

**P.S** I am only writing the new answer because I don't have enough reputation to write a comment on **[Cris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58800462/7221283)** answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another working version, with only basic loops/tests:

```
txt = ['assembly', '', 'py', 'tho', 'n', '', 'ja', 'va', '', 'rub', 'y', '', 'java', 'script', '', 'c++']

out = []
temp = ''

for s in txt:
   if s == '':
      if temp != '':
         out.append(temp) 
         temp = ''
      out.append('')
   else:
      temp = temp + s

if temp != '':
   out.append(temp)

out
```